# Do i need to update model.rb after migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I perform a migration (just adding a column) on my Users table do I need to manually add the new column to `attr_accessible` in `user.rb` in my models folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you do; that is, if you plan to use the new column in your forms or set attributes on it.

If you don't add the new column to `attr_accessible` in your model you'll get an `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error`.

In Rails 4 `attr_accessible` is extracted into a Gem.

Rails 4 uses `strong_paramters` instead. This is more flexible, and moves the filtering to the controller level.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if you want it to be accessible for mass assignment or not.  `attr_accessible` attributes basically take in their values from forms submitted by users, and the contents of those forms are basically just dumped into the database table for your model.  That's fine for attributes like name, email, etc.  However, for attributes like `admin?` that is either 1 for true or 0 for false, you don't want the user to be able to set that in a form.  Otherwise, when a user is signing up, he could just edit the html on his side to add a field called "admin," set its value to 1, and when he submits his form admin will be set to 1 for his user, and boom he is an admin.  Obviously this is a major security issue, so `admin` is an attribute you definitely do NOT want to include in `attr_accessible`.  You can think of `attr_accessible` as shorthand for `attr_accessible_for_mass_assignment_by_users`.